# Create a dynamic query .addField in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am having a problem is trying to create a dynamic part in my code.

```
for (let i = 1; i < row.length; i++){
  let sec = "row[" + i + "]." + Que;
  console.log(`${sec}`);
  embed.addField(row[i].Name, row[i].Pyrite, true);
};
message.channel.send(embed);
```

The above code work but I want to change the code so that row[i].Pyrite is created dynamically. I have tried the following but only get string (row[1].Pyrite), not the value.

```
embed.addField(row[i].Name, sec, true); 
embed.addField(row[i].Name, `${sec}`, true);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `Que` here? Do you want it as to when you have `Que = 'foo'` that `sec` will be `row[i].foo` and when `Que = bar` that `sec` will be `row[i].bar` etc.?

Comment: It will be a numeric value. row[i].x where X is the column name of the SQLLite table. for example:

row[1].Ice = 100-245
row[1].Coal = 200-234
etc..

So when I use the row[1].sec (and sec = Coal) is will return 200-234

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want by accessing properties with the [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). What this allows you to do is the following example:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Object name',
  description: 'Object description',
};

// Just calling the property 'name' directly
console.log(obj.name);

// Calling a property by bracket notation gives the same result
console.log(obj['name']);
```

By passing a string in the brackets it will search for a property on the object with the same name as the string. This can then be taken a step further by storing the string in a variable like this:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Object name',
  description: 'Object description',
};

// Just calling the property directly
console.log(obj.name);

// Calling the property by a string in bracket notation
console.log(obj['name']);

// Calling the propety by bracket notation with a variable containing a string
const objPropertyName = 'name';
console.log(obj[objPropertyName]);
```

All of these three methods result in the same output. Now putting this into your specific scenario, you can achieve what you want by using the following:

```js
const Que = 'Pyrite';

for (let i = 1; i < row.length; i++){
  // 'sec' will now equal row[i].Pyrite
  let sec = row[i][Que];

  console.log(sec);
  embed.addField(row[i].Name, sec, true);
};

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: Thanks mate, got working now by doing the following.

                    let sec = row[i][Que];
                    embed.addField(row[i].Name, `${sec}`, true);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to T. Dirks for helping with this. I got it working by doing the following:

```
                let sec = row[i][Que];
                embed.addField(row[i].Name, `${sec}`, true);
```